List all selected layers in PyQGIS
I would like to list all the selected layers in the QGIS Layers Panel with PyQGIS.
I'm looking for a PyQGIS function returning a list of all selected layers or a method to check if a layer is selected.
I tried iface.activeLayer() but it's only returning the last layer selected.
# not working (only last selected layer returned):
layers = iface.activeLayer()
print(layers)
>>> <QgsMapLayer: 'TOPO' (ogr)>

I also tried to loop on all layers but couldn't find a method to check if a layer is selected or not:
# not working either:
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
for layer_name, layer in layers.items():
    if layer.isSelected():
        print(layer)
>>> AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'isSelected'


You have selected layers (mouse-click on layer in tree / CTRL + mouse-click for multiple) and checked layers (checkbox clicked --> layers visible on the map canvas).
For selected layers you can do (answer from here):
iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()

For checked layers you can do (answer from here):
iface.mapCanvas().layers()

